# Azure Table Storage TableContinuationToken NextTableName purpose

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

It is sometimes said that when using Azure Tables there is effectively a 3rd key partitioning data - the Table Name itself.

I noticed when executing a Segmented query that the `TableContinuationToken` has a `NextTableName` property. What is the purpose of this property? It could be useful if a query could span multiple tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's for segmented queries if the full result can't be returned by a response.

Blockquote from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/query-tables :

> A query against the Table service may return a maximum of 1,000 tables at one time and may execute for a maximum of five seconds. If the result set contains more than 1,000 tables, if the query did not complete within five seconds, or if the query crosses the partition boundary, the response includes a custom header containing the x-ms-continuation-NextTableName continuation token. The continuation token may be used to construct a subsequent request for the next page of data. For more information about continuation tokens, see [Query Timeout and Pagination](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/query-timeout-and-pagination).

Comment: Thanks - I understand the reference is saying it is when you query the Table Service for a **list of Tables** in the account then it might take more than 5 seconds or return more than 1000 tables. Under those conditions the NextTableName is set. But its not possible to query data rows out of _multiple_ tables in a single operation (like an SQL union).